# Copy value from row, based on match of another row

Tags: r

Having a rough time approaching this problem with a large dataset. Essentially there are multiple rows for the same item. However, only one of the items contains the required value. I need to copy that value to all matching items.

Eg. below, I need item `100` to have a cost of `1203` for every row.

```
df = data.frame("item" = c(100, 100, 100, 105, 105, 102, 102, 102),
                "cost" = c(1203, 0, 0, 66, 0, 1200, 0, 0))
> df
  item cost
1  100 1203
2  100    0
3  100    0
4  105   66
5  105    0
6  102 1200
7  102    0
8  102    0
```

Like so:

```
df_wanted = data.frame("item" = c(100, 100, 100, 105, 105, 102, 102, 102),
                "cost" = c(1203, 1203, 1203, 66, 66, 1200, 1200, 1200))

> df_wanted
  item cost
1  100 1203
2  100 1203
3  100 1203
4  105   66
5  105   66
6  102 1200
7  102 1200
8  102 1200
```

Below is my attempt at I think an inefficient method:

```
for (row in 1:length(df$cost)){
  if (df$cost[row] == 0){
    df$cost[row] = df$cost[row-1]
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a representative example.  Do you have any other cases where it would fail i.e. more than one non zero elements for each 'item'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up going with after revisiting this problem as a `left_join()`. Which makes more sense to me intuitively though it may not be the best solution.

The original DF below.

```
df = tibble("item" = as.factor(c(100, 100, 100, 105, 105, 102, 102, 102)),
            "cost" = c(1203, 0, 0, 66, 0, 0, 1200, 0))

> df
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  item   cost
  <fct> <dbl>
1 100    1203
2 100       0
3 100       0
4 105      66
5 105       0
6 102       0
7 102    1200
8 102       0
```

Create an 'index' of item-value pairs

```
df_index <- df %>% 
  group_by(item) %>% 
  arrange(-cost) %>% 
  slice(1) 

> df_index
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   item [3]
  item   cost
  <fct> <dbl>
1 100    1203
2 102    1200
3 105      66
```

Finally, join the dataframes by `item` to fill in the empty row values.

```
df_joined <- df %>% 
  left_join(df_index, by="item")

> df_joined
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  item  cost.x cost.y
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 100     1203   1203
2 100        0   1203
3 100        0   1203
4 105       66     66
5 105        0     66
6 102        0   1200
7 102     1200   1200
8 102        0   1200
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to group by `item` and then replace `0` in `cost` with the last non-zero value. In each group, `cummax(which(cost != 0))` will give the index of the last non-zero value.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(item) %>%
    mutate(cost = cost[cummax(which(cost != 0))]) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 8 x 2
#   item  cost
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1   100  1203
#2   100  1203
#3   100  1203
#4   105    66
#5   105    66
#6   102  1200
#7   102  1200
#8   102  1200
```

Base R equivalent is

```
transform(df, cost = ave(cost, item, FUN = function(x) x[cummax(which(x != 0))]))
```

Comment: This might be what I need, can you explain the `cost[cumsum(cost != 0)]` part? I expected the code to involve `max()` or similar.

Comment: The first solution involving cumsum sort of worked. The solution with the `which()` statement seems to be throwing an error both in my test and real data: `>replacement has 3 rows, data has 8`

Answer (score 1):

here is one option.  After grouping by 'item', subset the 'cost' where the 'cost' is not 0 and select the `first` element

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(item) %>% 
   mutate(cost = first(cost[cost!=0))
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   item [3]
#   item  cost
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1   100  1203
#2   100  1203
#3   100  1203
#4   105    66
#5   105    66
#6   102  1200
#7   102  1200
#8   102  1200
```

Comment: This seems to give me 1203 for all item rows. Not sure if i've pasted incorrectly somehow.

Comment: @tastycanofmalk  I used only your example Try with `dplyr::mutate(cost = ` in case you have also loaded `plyr`

Comment: Ah okay I see, it works perfectly now both in the example and from what I can see in my actual data as well. Ideally the data is all like this but I have found some edge cases where I have multiple values in `cost` (rather than `0`). I will need to figure out what to do with these at a later time I think.

Comment: @tastycanofmalk  That is the reason I used `first`, but you could change it to `min` or `max` if that is what you want.  Also, I would anticipate some groups having only `0` values.  In that case, what would be the output.  My earlier version was `mutate(cost = max(cost))` and it should work fine